# How to read streams from video files on iPhone by their absolute path

Tags: ios, video, xamarin.forms, streamreader, phasset

I got stuck when trying to get streams from videos on iPhone. It's an `Xamarin.Forms` project.

Firstly, I got VideoURL by `PHAsset.RequestContentEditingInput` like this

```
PHAsset videoAsset;
...
videoAsset.RequestContentEditingInput(new PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions(), (contentEditingInput, dictInfo) =>
                {
                    if (videoAsset.MediaType == PHAssetMediaType.Video)
                    {
                        AVFoundation.AVUrlAsset avUrlAsset = (AVFoundation.AVUrlAsset)contentEditingInput.AvAsset;
                        string VideoURL = avUrlAsset.Url.AbsoluteString;
```

VideoURL looks like `file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/108APPLE/IMG_8078.MOV`.

Then I want to get video stream by `VideoURL` using `StreamReader` like this

```
var streamReader = new StreamReader(videoURL);
```

Or using File.Open like this

```
var fileStream = File.Open(videoURL, FileMode.Open);
```

But both methods will throw System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException and said

Could not find a part of the path `/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BC860AE6-B358-405D-B2CD-47ECF853F365/test.app/file:/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/108APPLE/IMG_8078.MOV`.

As you can see, it automatically added my app path before the video URL, and thus can't find the video file.

So my question is, how to get stream by a video's absolute path? Thanks.

Comment: you are using the URL and file path interchangeably - they are different things.

Comment: @Jason Thanks for reminding. Yes, in this case, URL is actually file path. But this doesn't matter. I name it 'VideoURL' because some videos are using real URLs

Comment: `file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/108APPLE/IMG_8078.MOV` is NOT a path

Comment: @Jason Hum... you're right. So could I get stream by url? Or could I use file path like `/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/108APPLE/IMG_8078.MOV`? What I'm trying to do is to upload videos onto Azure Storage by using blob.UploadFromFileAsync or blob.UploadFromStreamAsync

Comment: why don't you just use MediaPlugin?

Comment: @Jason Thanks for replying. I did use MediaPlugin for video recording. After recorded, I could get the file path. But I also need to list all existed videos and let user decide which one to upload. And I don't want to use UIImagePickerController because I need to list not only local but also online videos

Comment: @Jason Thanks for help. I tried to use file path like `/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/108APPLE/IMG_8078.MOV` and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried using file path like

```
/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/108APPLE/IMG_8078.MOV
```

i.e. removed "file://", then it works.